# Does Jinja2 Work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps-api-3, jinja2

I have been trying to get this to work for quite a while now:

```
{% for record in records %}

var GPSlocation = "(37.7699298, -93.4469157)";
var LatLng = GPSlocation.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(", ")
var Lat = parseFloat(LatLng[0]);
var Lng = parseFloat(LatLng[1]);

var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: record.GPSlocation,
    title: record.title
});

//add the marker to the map
marker.setMap(map);

{% endfor %}
```

And it works fine when I hard code the variables in there but otherwise I just won't do anything. When I just print them out in the html I have all the data I wanted in the record variables but when I try to use it in JavaScript it just doesn't work. Any ideas?

So I need to put a JSON encoding filter onto the Jinja2 system and I am guessing it would look something like this:

```
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                           jinja_env.filters['json_encode'] = json.dumps,
                           autoescape = True)
```

Comment: You don't use `record` in the example. It's unclear what your problem is, or what you are trying to accomplish. Also note that the javascript won't interact with the template markup.

Comment: @Marcin whoops sorry I just copied my hard coded version but I just fixed it up. I am trying to access the attributes of record to set the marker values

Comment: if the Javascript won't interact with the jinja2 markup language how would you advise to get that information in there?

Comment: As icktoofay shows you, you must evaluate the markup variable to have it paste its value into your generated javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not like that. You could instead do something like this:

```
{% for record in records %}
addRecord({
    title: {{ title|json_encode }}, // assuming you have json_encode set up as a filter
    position: {
        latitude: {{ record.position.latitude|json_encode }},
        longitude: {{ record.position.longitude|json_encode }}
    }
});
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: how am I able to setup json_encode as a filter? I can't find a thing on it on google

Comment: With the `json` module imported, right after you create your Jinja2 environment (here named `jinja_env`): `jinja_env.filters['json_encode'] = json.dumps`

Comment: I added my code changes to the code. is that what you were intending to say?  it is telling me I have a parentheses error but I tried a few variations without success

Comment: @clifgray: Sorry, I meant on the line after the closing `)` of the call to `jinja2.Environment`

Comment: Ah okay thanks. So I've almost got it working and I have been looking it up but the JSON is spitting out a "&#34;" at the beginning and end of the string.  any idea how to get this off?

Comment: @clifgray: Oh, I just realized that this would conflict with `autoescape`. You'll need to make Jinja2 not escape the results of `json_encode`. I think you can do that by using `|json_encode|safe` rather than `|json_encode` in the template.

Comment: sorry you had to babystep me through that, I had been staring at the problem for too long.  but i just got it to work. thanks so much!